# Windows 10 fullscreen in only portion of the screen

Tags: windows-10, desktop, fullscreen

I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that when you fullscreen an application in Windows 10, it would only take up part of the screen. I am planning on purchasing a 34" monitor and I was wondering if it would be possible to have a full-screened application like zoom or youtube videos only take up half of the screen so I could work on something else on the other side. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Snap settings built-in to Windows (as John answered) is not robust enough for your needs, [Microsoft PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) includes a utility called FancyZones:

> FancyZones is a window manager that is designed to make it easy to arrange and snap windows into efficient layouts for your workflow and also to restore these layouts quickly. FancyZones allows the user to define a set of window locations for a desktop that are drag targets for windows. When the user drags a window into a zone, the window is resized and repositioned to fill that zone.

Download PowerToys here: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/

FancyZones overview:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones

Comment: I concur with the recommendation of FancyZones, but does it actually do what the question asks of it? That is to say, allow full-screened applications to be moved around. If so, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, go to Settings, System, Multi-Tasking and set the Snap to Settings so that you can snap a Zoom or You Tube window to the side of the screen and work in the rest of the screen.

This is a close as you can get to separate windows in the same physical screen.  It does work quite well.